# How to dynamically add a column and row to calculate total in each cell in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple sample data like this

```
var data = {
    "Lines": [
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.5},{"Hours": 2.50},{"Hours": 3.75}]}, 
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.1},{"Hours": 2.00},{"Hours": 4.75}]},
        {"Entries": [{"Hours": 1.2},{"Hours": 3.00},{"Hours": 2.12}]
    }]
}
```

Here is my model

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this
    self.List = ko.observableArray([])

    self.LoadData = function () {
        var data = {
            "Lines": [
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.5},{"Hours": 2.50},{"Hours": 3.75}]}, 
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.1},{"Hours": 2.00},{"Hours": 4.75}]},
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 1.2},{"Hours": 3.00},{"Hours": 2.12}]
            }]
        }
        self.List(ko.mappings.fromJS(data.Lines))
    ////this makes every child observable
    }
    self.LoadData()
}

$('document').ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
})
```

Here is my view

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mon  1 </th>
            <th>Mon  2 </th>
            <th>Mon  3 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach:Lines'>
        <tr data-bind='foreach:$data.Entries'>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:Hours"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is sample view

[image]

here is the output i want

[image]

You can see i am adding a column and a row which need to add and these should be observables. how can i do it. I have no idea where to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a computedObservable to each row (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kL79d/4/) :

html:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mon  1 </th>
            <th>Mon  2 </th>
            <th>Mon  3 </th>
            <th>Total </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach:List'>
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach:Entries-->
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:Hours, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"/>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:Total"></span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this
    self.List = ko.observableArray([])

    self.LoadData = function () {
        var data = {
            "Lines": [
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.5},{"Hours": 2.50},{"Hours": 3.75}]}, 
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 5.1},{"Hours": 2.00},{"Hours": 4.75}]},
                {"Entries": [{"Hours": 1.2},{"Hours": 3.00},{"Hours": 2.12}]
            }]
        }                       
        self.List(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Lines)())
    ////this makes every child observable
    }

    self.applyTotals = function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.List(), function(vm){
            vm.Total = ko.computed(function(){
                var s = 0;
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Entries(), function(entry){
                    var p = parseFloat(entry.Hours(), 10);
                    if (!isNaN(p)) {
                        s += p;
                    }
                });
                return s;
            }, vm);
        });
    }

    self.LoadData();
    console.log(self.List());
    self.applyTotals();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

To get the column totals, do the same thing on the vertical. For easier access to the data values, you might want to keep the data in data structure which allows easy iteration for both rows and columns.

Comment: this has resolved half of the problem. Can you please help me do this for vertical calculation too?

Comment: @raheelshan sure, here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kL79d/6/ Remember to accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks i was only dragging your attention. Can't i do it dynamically instead of manually adding a row. I mean as you see tds are generated dynamically. So i want to handle it dynamically. there somes sometime 15 or sometimes more then 15

Comment: Ok, here's a fiddle with a Line constructor, for adding more lines. (http://jsfiddle.net/kL79d/8/) Data is now passed through the constructor instead of building it with ko.mapping. The same thing can be done for the columns. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is really helpful. I like knockout and you are geniues presenting such solution

Comment: pity i can only give you +1 no more

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation for the mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), there's a section called "Customizing object construction using 'create'".  This shows how you can control the mapping of the json data to an observable object -- including augmenting the object with additional functionality (like the computedObservable @pax162 mentioned).

It's basically the same approach @pax162 mentioned, but in a more automated fashion.